# Python printing backslash without using it

Tags: python, eval

I have the following issue. I need to represent `'\'` in Python without using `'\'`. Is there a way to achieve this using the functions `print()`, `eval()`, `str()` or `repr()`?

Comment: You can try `print(chr(92))`, but it doesn't use the functions you list.

Comment: maybe an alternative to `chr()`?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you can't use a literal backslash? In strings, two backslashes escape to a single literal backslash. `print('\\')` would produce `'\'` for example.

Comment: @sytech yes I know that, but i am 'not allowed' to use `'\'` so the goal is to somehow circumvent it

Comment: possibly using `string.punctuation` from the `string` module. `string.punctuation[23]` is a backslash.

Answer (score 1):

A first resource is [`chr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr), e.g., `chr(92)`.

If `chr` does not fit your needs, you would get the backslash from "somewhere".

Under Windows, a possible "safe" place to look for is in path names.
E.g.,

```
import os
print( str(os.getcwd())[2] )   # (Almost certainly) gives you a backslash
print( os.sep )                # Gives you a backslash
```

Or, you may have it stored somewhere you know, and go look for it.
E.g., in a file, written in memory, etc.
I am not sure these are acceptable options for you.

Answer (score 0):

You may do this with `eval`. As `eval` simply takes a string as an argument, you're arguably not using the `chr` built-in function directly ;)

Take this as an example and do not wonder about the double backslash, it's because a single one is for escaping characters:

```
>>> backslash = eval('chr(92)')
>>> backslash
'\\'
>>> len(backslash)
1
>>> print(eval('chr(92)'))
\
>>>
```